# emoji.url works for internal emojis but not ones from other servers

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm making a discord bot and one of my functions is going to be getting the source image for an emoji for... *thieving purposes*.

I have created a simple function to get the URL for the emoji sent in the command and return that in chat, which gets converted by discord automatically into the emoji source image. Perfect!

BUT! It doesn't work on emojis from outside the server. Emojis from within the server work perfectly fine, including animated ones, but emojis (both static and animated) from outside the server do not get returned.

My current code goes as follows:

```
@bot.command(brief='Allows you to steal an emoji', description='Will return the image file for a requested emoji', usage='[emoji](can be from anywhere and animated if you have nitro)')
async def steal(ctx, emoji: discord.Emoji):
    receivedcommand(ctx)    
    await ctx.send(emoji.url)
```

How can I change this code to work for emojis not within the server that the bot's in? I assume I gotta do some funky shit with IDs but I don't know where to start.

Help?

Edit: Error message

```
Ignoring exception in command steal:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vyladence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Vyladence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Vyladence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Vyladence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\Vyladence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 552, in transform
    return await self.do_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "C:\Users\Vyladence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 505, in do_conversion
    return await self._actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "C:\Users\Vyladence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 451, in _actual_conversion
    ret = await instance.convert(ctx, argument)
  File "C:\Users\Vyladence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 723, in convert
    raise EmojiNotFound(argument)
discord.ext.commands.errors.EmojiNotFound: Emoji "<:10_years:578822331766538240>" not found.
```

Comment: Can you give more info than "it doesn't work"? What happens? What error does it throw? What weird results does it give?

Comment: sorry! I have an error handler and didn't think to include the error message. it's in my post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For external emojis, you need to use [`discord.PartialEmoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=emoji#discord.PartialEmoji):

```py
@bot.command(brief='Allows you to steal an emoji', description='Will return the image file for a requested emoji', usage='[emoji](can be from anywhere and animated if you have nitro)')
async def steal(ctx, emoji: discord.PartialEmoji):
    receivedcommand(ctx)    
    await ctx.send(emoji.url)
```

If you use [`discord.Emoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=emoji#discord.Emoji), your bot needs to be in the guild the emoji comes from.

Comment: Well, that was a stupidly easy fix. Thank you!